# Returning array elements in intervals

Tags: c, arrays, intervals

I have an array of x elements that I am trying to print in 5 element intervals as a user presses a next button.  If my array is int `a[14] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};` an example display would be.

```
1,2,3,4,5
next
6,7,8,9,10
next
11,12,13,14
next
1,2,3,4,5
..
..
```

How should I approach solving this?

Comment: Why is this so hard (i.e. use a index to track)? What have you tried?

Comment: Write each step on a piece of paper and go through it step by step. This problem isn't that hard to think about. Remember that computers work step by step so no reason you shouldn't be able to think through this one easily.

Comment: Start by writing *code*. When the only "problem" in a posted question is not having written any code to answer the question first, its not going to live long. Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that exhibits the specific problem you're encountering implementing the aforementioned algorithm. If you're not tried to do so yet, [perhaps you should](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
for(i=0;i<x;i+=5)
{
 for(j=i;((j<i+5) && (j<x));j++)
 {
  printf("%d,",a[j]);
 }
 //Wait for next character here
 printf("\nnext\n");
}
```

Edit: Fixed an issue with the code for arrays of non-multiples of 5.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

void interval_print(int *a, int *end, int len){
    static int *start=NULL;
    static int *current;
    int i;
    if(start != a)
        current = start = a;
    for(i=0;i<len && current != end;++i)
        printf("%d%c", *current++, (i==len-1 ? '\n' : ','));
    if(current == end){
        printf("%d\n", *current);
        current = start;
    }
}

int main(){
    int a[14] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14};
    for(;;){
        char ch;
        interval_print(a, &a[13], 5);
        printf("next\n");
        printf("continue?\ninput y or n : ");
        scanf(" %c", &ch);
        if(ch == 'n' || ch == 'N')
            break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```